# Fixed array length with an optional item

Tags: typescript

I have an interface defined in my app:

```
interface someInterface {
    one: string;
    two: string;
}
```

One of my function parameters should always accept a homogeneous array of 1 or 2 elements, something like this:

```
// second item should be optional
[{ one: 'anyString', two: 'anyString' }, { one: 'anotherString', two: 'anotherString' }]
```

I would expect that one of these types assigned to the parameter would work:

```
1. [someInterface, someInterface | null]
2. [someInterface, someInterface | undefined]
3. [someInterface, someInterface?]
4. someInterface[]
```

But 1 and 2 expect the seconds item, at least in the form of `null` or `undefined`. 3 is not a valid typescript code. 4 accepts unlimited amount of values.

**Question:** How to define a type of array, which accepts 1 or 2 homogeneous values: in this case, the first value should always be of `someInterface` type and should always be present. The second optional value, if present, should also be of type `someInterface`.

Basically, I am looking for a shortcut of this (i.e. in case the array should accept from 1 to 5 values):

```
[someInterface, someInterface] | [someInterface]
```

Comment: What you're describing are tuple types, except for 4. Do you want `[someInterface] | [someInterface, someInterface]`?

Comment: 3 will be valid when TypeScript 3.0 comes out, as part of support for [tuples in test/spread positions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897).

Comment: @jcalz Sir, I can't stop getting pieces of valuable information from you! Thank you very much for responding to the questions :)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Added clarification as the last 2 lines of the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can define the type as "either a tuple with one value or a tuple with two values", which will produce an array which can be used just like a regular array:

```
var SomeType = [someInterface] | [someInterface, someInterface];
```

Comment: Thanks! But I was trying to find a less repetitive way of declaring. This piece of information was missing in my unedited answer initially.

Comment: This works well until we have to use .push, please check this question for context https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69685408/how-to-make-an-item-in-a-fixed-array-of-promises-optional-using-typescript

Answer (score -1):

After tinkering with the code and going through different answers on the web as well as typescript documentation, I managed to achieve the desired outcome with this type:

```
type SomeType = { 0: someInterface, 1?: someInterface }
```

P.S. I realized, that this allows for the third value to be added, so if there are more reliable solutions, please, add your version

Comment: *"better"* how? This doesn't let you treat a `SomeType` as an array, for example (e.g. it doesn't have `push`), but that may not actually be a problem for your use case.

Comment: @jonrsharpe added clarification. If the type would allow to treat SomeType as an array as well, it would be great.