# How to make an item in a fixed array of Promises optional using Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, es6-promise

I have something like this:

```js
const promises:
            | [Promise<boolean>, Promise<boolean>]
            | [Promise<boolean>, Promise<boolean>, Promise<{ currency: string; price: number }>] = [
            User.is1337(user._id),
            PurchasedItemsModel.exists({
                type: 'course',
                userid: user._id,
                slug: courseSlug
            })
        ]
```

I want to type the `promises` variable properly.

Later down in the code I push to the promises array as follows:

```js
promises.push(
                getSingleCoursePrice({
                    slug: courseSlug,
                    country,
                    percentOff: couponData?.percentOff || 0
                })
            )
```

and when I push like this, typescript gives me an error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can use the following as a workaround:

```
    promises = [
        ...promises,
        getSingleCoursePrice({
            slug: courseSlug,
            country,
            percentOff: couponData?.percentOff || 0
        })
    ];
```

**UPDATED:**

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsIwOYFNkAquIyACgE7oC2qIuAPAQHwAUAbsADYK4BcMBAJT8K1Wg2YwA3gCgY8mOXwJyWDt1wBuGQF8ZMzvhgAHSjTohechQB8YAbVHmGAI3TpDwCEwA0MJ%20L0bh64XkwAutbydo5mgcGe3n4BdEHuib7%20calSMFAqStBg-CTkqBDYmiZlUHwwEAhULrjkMDoRMAC8DlE4%20EQkKbgsyOQ8gj69eITEZNnDo%20My4doypmIWXT0KMAB0%20%20vOIJM70wNzG8O5%20eSFUMUwAOSPfqaotfwADG2Cy6tDuy4nBYh3EIF%20O12yAAFrgICwWPYYAlQhAAIx%20FFeABMfnQLgAVrgoMg0TBwoIukw8pgQCFdpx0NgWFj0Zj0qjcTB8USSWjBIJNEA).

Comment: Yes, this works. Thankyou

Comment: But this also poses a problem, when I am doing Promise.all(promises)

Comment: Any errors thrown?

Comment: Yes, it said it could not resolve [Promise<boolean>, Promise<boolean>] in Promise.all(promises)

Comment: Interesting, I can't replicate that error in TS Playground. Updated answer with that.

Comment: Try using async await instead of .then, check this https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsIwOYFNkAquIyACgE7oC2qIuAPAQHwAUAbsADYK4BcMBAJT8K1Wg2YwA3gCgY8mOXwJyWDt1wBuGQF8ZMzvhgAHSjTohechQB8YAbVHmGAI3TpDwCEwA0MJ+L0bh64XkwAutbydo5mgcGe3n4BdEHuib7+calSMFAqStBg-CTkqBDYmiZlUHwwEAhULrjkMDoRMAC8DlE4+EQkKbgsyOQ8gj69eITEZNnDo+My4doypmIWXT0KMAB0++vOIJM70wNzG8O5+eSFUMUwAOSPfqaotfwADG2Cy6tQmBIMGALlg3VAkCgLEEXSY0l6AIgQPswD8Lj8UHCW2AAHdgKhkFlLrsuJwWIdxCBfnpegB6Wl7ZAAC1wEBYLHsMASoQgAEY0ekeQAmPzoFwAK1wUGQvJg4RhnThiJAIV2nHQ2BY3K8-K5gq8IpgYsl0t5gkEmiAA

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround could be:

```
const promises: | [Promise<boolean>, Promise<boolean>, Promise<{ currency: string; price: number }> | undefined] = [
    User.is1337(user._id),
    PurchasedItemsModel.exists({
        type: 'course',
        userid: user._id,
        slug: courseSlug
    }),
    undefined // Will filter this out later
]
```

Now I can push whatever I want:

```
promises.push(Promise.resolve(true))
promises.push(Promise.resolve({ currency: '$', price: 1}))
promises.push(getSingleCoursePrice({
    slug: courseSlug,
    country,
    percentOff: couponData?.percentOff || 0
  })
)
```

Additional step that you will need to do at last:

`promises.filter(o => o);`

Comment: Interesting workaround

Comment: but now I'm thinking wouldn't I be better off just using any 

Comment: You can but any will remove all the restrictions on the value types, you will be able to push non promises, strings, numbers directly. While the current type check only allows 3 values, boolean, your custom object and undefined.

Comment: that's right. Thanks though man